# How to compare fields of unrelated classes?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, compare, comparator

`products` is a list of instances of different classes(Class A,Class B that are extended by abstract class C)
Both classes have method `getNumber()`

```
public void sortByNumber() {
        Collections.sort(products, new Comparator<T>() {
            public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
                return ((T) o1).getNumber().compareTo(((T o2).getNumber());
            }
        });
    }
```

I need to get access to `o1.getNumber()` and `o2.getNumber()` methods to compare fields .
There is error:

```
The method getNumber() is undefined for  the type T
```

Comment: Maybe you want to implement a `Comparator<C>` (`Comparator<Product>`) instead of `Comparator<T>`? You have to declare an `abstract` `getNumber()` method in `C`, if you haven’t yet.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown how the type parameter `T` is defined, but if there is no upper bound, then the compiler can't assume that there are any methods except those belonging to `Object` available to call on `o1` and `o2`.

If your instances of different classes all implement some interface that defines `getNumber`, then all you have to do is add the upper bound for that interface.

```
public class YourClass<T extends HasNumber>  // Your names may vary
```

If your classes don't implement that interface, then you will need to create such an interface and have those classes implement that interface.

Comment: All I need is to sort that list of products. But when I try to compare products they can be of different classes.